# Axis label values in charts

Tags: c#, .net

**Code snippet:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length -1; i++)
    {
        series1.Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble(vals[i])); 
        series1.AxisLabel = date[i];
    }
```

**This is what I have:**

[image: 1]

**Whereas this is what I want** (estimation of dates)**:**

[image: 2]

Ideally I would like the axis to start on the first day of a month and end on the last. The arrays are both the same length, and both contain strings. Anyone succeeded with this before?

The data range may be a few days, a week, several months or a year, but I need to plot a months worth of data.

I am using .net 4 charts, the kind that come bundled with visual studio.

Comment: Not the answer but by doing `vals.Length -1` you will not iterate over the last value.

Comment: I can't do this because then it would exceed the bounds of the array. This is the correct data, just need to extract the relevant data labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length -1; i++)
 {
     series1.Points.Add(Convert.ToDouble(vals[i])); 
     series1.AxisLabel = date[i]; 
 }
//replace this


for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length -1; i++)
 {
     series1.Points.AddXY(Convert.ToString(date[i]), Convert.ToDouble(vals[i])); 
 }

series1.AxisLabel = date[0]; 
//with this
```

This plots a chart with points placed above (although slightly off centre) the relevant date points. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Adding the x-values as strings will space the points evenly, i.e. not according to actual the x-values, though.